# SOAP Service Connection return error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365

I created the SOAP service in data source for the third party API WSDL available.but when I used to use this service from `DATA VIEW` in page, it show error given below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred due to User permission to use the SOAP service. Before using the Soap service , conform the permission